# Cannot find name 'ReadableStream'

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I have a project that uses @types/whatwg-fetch version 0.0.32.

When running my project i get the following error.

```
ERROR in <project-root>/node_modules/@types/whatwg-fetch/index.d.ts
(97,11): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStream'.
```

I have added @types/whatwg-streams version 0.0.4, but it still fails with the same error. Bumping the whatwg-fetch to the newest 0.0.33, just ads one more line of error:

```
ERROR in /home/vojda/workspace/honeybee/acquisition/node_modules/@types/whatwg-fetch/index.d.ts
(32,44): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStream'.

ERROR in /home/vojda/workspace/honeybee/acquisition/node_modules/@types/whatwg-fetch/index.d.ts
(102,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStream'.
```

Does someone knows why is this happening?

I suppose that it is happening because something is caching something. I think so, because when the project was deleted from another computer and recloned from the repository this error was gone, but showed again in some time.

If needed, I will upload more files.

Comment: Have you installed `@types/node`? They should contain type definitions for `ReadableStream`.

Comment: Yes, it is installed.

Comment: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/20608 - I have logged a bug and am waiting to see what will happen. After that I will update this question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to reference @types/whatwg-fetch at all because whatwg-fetch is in global scope and implements standards that are already defined in the standard lib definition files.  My project doesn't use any @types for whatwg-fetch and I reference ReadableStream without issue.  Here's a link to another question that talks about this:
[whatwg-fetch new typescript 2.5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46847905/whatwg-fetch-new-typescript-2-5-3) .