# whatwg-fetch new typescript 2.5.3

Tags: javascript, typescript, fetch

In my typescript project I am using "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3" this is latest version of this poly fill ans as types I am using this version "@types/whatwg-fetch": "0.0.33" and everything works well for me when i used typescript version "2.2.0".

But now I would like to update typescript to latest version "2.5.3" and that is my problem wen I try co compile this then I got bambilon types errors first what i got is this error

in

**D:\Projects\AppStoreSource\appstore\source\AppStore\node_modules\@types\whatwg-fetch\index.d.ts
(11,13): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'fetch'.**

Yes true is that on line 11 is this  declare

```
declare let fetch: typeof window.fetch;
```

Or

**D:\Projects\AppStoreSource\appstore\source\AppStore\node_modules\@types\whatwg-fetch\index.d.ts
(13,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'HeadersInit'.**

So did some one  try use "whatwg-fetch" and latest typescript or I potential problem is in something like loaders etc, for me it looks like I have two definition or i do not know ... i am lost :-) ???

Or is there alternative for other poly fill that is compatible with typescript "2.5.3"??? I would like avoid to fork and rewrite typings.

Thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer on this one is that you don't need to add types for fetch, as TypeScript has them in the lib.d.ts file now.

So if you remove the `@types/whatwg-fetch` development dependency, your program should compile.

This is very often the exact reason you get errors in a definition file, especially with anything based on emerging standards.