# Typescript error: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'fetch'

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, typescript, fetch-api

I am working on a proof of concept to fetch some simple JSON data from JSON-server to display in my react app. In doing so I am trying to call fetch to load the data directly. When I do so.

> **ERROR:** "cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'fetch'.

My question is, when working in regular Typescript, how can I get around this issue?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../HeaderBar/HeaderBar.css';

type StatusBarProps = {};
type StatusBarState = {
    launch_timer: boolean;
    foreGroundTimer: number;

};
class StatusBar extends Component<StatusBarProps, StatusBarState> {
    timerId: number;
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            launch_timer: true,
            foreGroundTimer: -1,
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        window.fetch('localhost:3000/StatusComponent').then(results => {
            return results.json();
        }).then(data => {
            let systemOff = 'green';
            let systemOn = 'gray';
            let statusBarBlocks = data.StatusComponent.map((Status) => {
                return(
                    <div className="blockBar" id={Status.id} key={Status.key} style={{ backgroundColor: (this.state.foreGroundTimer >= Status.id) ? systemOff : systemOn }}> {Status.Name} </div>
                );
            });
            this.setState({statusBarBlocks: statusBarBlocks});
        });
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timerId);
    }
    tick() {
        this.setState({ launch_timer: !this.state.launch_timer, foreGroundTimer: (this.state.foreGroundTimer + 1) % 26 });
    }
    render() {

        return (
            <div className="location">
                <div className="col-xs-6">
                {this.state.statusBarBlocks}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default StatusBar;
```

edit 1: the location of the issue is @types/whatwg-fetch/index.d.ts which leads me to believe this is an issue with typescript. I have implemented Isomorphic-fetch to no avail.

Comment: Do you import fetch from isomorphic-fetch package?

Comment: @SlawaEremkin I do not, but would that cause this issue?

Comment: What part of the code causes the issue? Try removing everything else

Comment: @Bergi The issue seems to arise at the window.fetch inside componentdidmount.

Comment: @jpearsonNode "*seems to*" - have you confirmed it? Does it need to be inside componentdidmount for that? Do you need any imports for it to arise? Does it need to be called? Please do some debugging.

Comment: @Bergi The specific issue that arises is error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'fetch'. It does need to be inside componentdidmount specifically for the purpose of receiving persistent updates, as this is being fed on a stream of data. I do not need any imports, as I understand fetch is native. I

Comment: @jpearsonNode I meant "does it need to be in there *to cause the error*", of course

Comment: You don't need to do fetch, just `import fetch from isomorphic fetch` and use it way

Comment: @win can you clarify your statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in working to discover the cause of this issue. I found that I had an overlap where fetch was being declared in both the Lib file, and in @types/whatwg-fetch. Uninstalling this dependency allowed the program to compile. Resolving the issue.

[whatwg-fetch new typescript 2.5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46847905/whatwg-fetch-new-typescript-2-5-3/46848251)

Found at this SO post. Credit to Fenton for this answer.